# Returning to UK using C Business Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel

I have a C-business-visitor visa to the UK (multiple entry visa), that I used to represent my NGO in a conference on November. My visa is still valid. Can I use it again to enter to the UK 
to present again my NGO and plan for a training in citizen journalism for young girls in London?

I have a stamp on my visa of the date I entered the UK in.

If yes, what do I have to provide at the airport?

Comment: Is it a multiple entry visa? or a single entry visa? this should be stated somewhere in the visa.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is a multiple entry visa

Comment: @GayotFow that makes the question not a duplicate of the one you linked.

Comment: @MeNoTalk, how so?

Comment: @GayotFow this is multi-entry visa, as she just commented.

Comment: @MeNoTalk, so is the other one.  The title 'single visa' = 'the same visa'. Read the question.  Also read this one http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44777/visit-uk-with-business-visitor-visa-again-for-tourism-purposes/44786#44786  and take your pick :)

Comment: @GayotFow ok, got the point and voted to close as a dupe

Comment: @MeNoTalk, I edited the title on the other one

Comment: So i will be able to use it, since it was issued on Oct 20,2014 WITHOUT GOING THROUGH a British Immigration Office?