# Visit UK like a tourist with C-Visit-business

Tags: visas, uk

I am confused a little I want to attend a UK like a tourist but my visa type is C-Visit-Business. I read a lot of information but can't understand can I go to UK or can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! But keep in mind some stuffs:

- Print the flight tickets, specially for two ways because they can ask for it;
- Print the hotel booking or whatever you gonna stay and keep in mind that if you gonna stay for 10 days you will need 10 days booked;
- Buy some pounds before you go, they may ask how much you have with you.

Sometimes they also ask about what itinerary you are going to do, what kind of places you would like to visit and so on. Be natural.

Nice reference, original source: https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very good explanation. But could you please provide some other legal links that prove it? I read the link that you add but it is not contains tourism or leisure purposes.

Comment: @AndrewKravets I edited my question with the government link

Comment: I saw it and careful read but as I know there is a rules changes since 24 April 2015 and in the document no information from tourism.

Comment: About 2015 I don't know, I went to London last year, anyway, which country are you from? Maybe your passport allows you to visit without a visa.

Comment: From Ukraine so i need a visa =(

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

If you have a UK C-Visit-Business visa it means you applied prior to 24 April 2015.  On that date the C-Visit-Business was abolished.

In order to manage the transition, Parliament approved the plan of having all existing C-Visit-Business visas [automatically convert to Standard Visit visas](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/statement-of-changes-to-the-immigration-rules-hc1025-26-february-2015).  It wouldn't make sense to suddenly cancel everyone's visa, would it?

There's some really good links here:  [Travelling on Business visa to UK for tourism purposes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47950/travelling-on-business-visa-to-uk-for-tourism-purposes)

So yes, you can use your existing business visit visa for tourism or any other permitted activity.

And there's more information in the [canonical](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47950/travelling-on-business-visa-to-uk-for-tourism-purposes).